# How do I get SQL Server auto-complete working in NetBeans?

Tags: sql-server, netbeans

I'm using NetBeans with the jTDS JDBC driver connecting to a Microsoft SQL Server. However, I've been unable to get the SQL auto-complete functionality to work. Any ideas how to enable this?

Answer (score 0):

Auto-complete is automatically enabled in Netbeans, but you must manually trigger it when you want to use it.

Open a SQL Command window and begin typing your query.  To trigger auto-complete, press CTRL+Space and a list will pop up with your available options.